# ProGuard settings for Kamcord SDK (v1.7 or even the latest v1.9)

Tags: android, proguard, video-capture

Title says it all. Does anyone have the ProGuard settings to use for Kamcord v1.7 or v1.9? I am hitting so many warnings I have several left and I am not certain how to exempt Kamcord's references from the ProGuard process.

I can turn off proguard and and and can deploy.

Here is the warning I think matter...

```
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
 [proguard] Warning: com.c.a.KC_s: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
```

The last bit of the ANT build (using proguard)

```
 [proguard] Note: there were 7 references to unknown classes.
 [proguard]       You should check your configuration for typos.
 [proguard] Note: there were 60 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
 [proguard]       You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
 [proguard]       (using '-keep').
 [proguard] Note: there were 14 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 [proguard] Warning: there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

BUILD FAILED
```

Here is the settings that have got me this far in my proguard-project.txt...

```
#kamcord (best guesses)
-keep class com.kamcord.** { *; }
-keep class com.c.** { *; }
-keep class com.a.** { *; }
-keep class a.** { *; }
-keep class com.googlecode.mp4parser.** { *; }
-keep class com.coremedia.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep class libcore.icu.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.kamcord.**
```

There is a metric ton of additional ProGuard config happening prior to this... So maybe some ProGuard experts might be able to clue me on on what's missing in the question to make it answerable.